# Free (at the time) Addon that gives 20 F-Stops to Blender Cameras

Tags: cycles-render-engine, add-on, camera

Months and months ago, I remember seeing someone from a movie company (I think) that made a Blender camera plugin aka addon for free that gave Blender's cameras as many F-Stops as the human eye.  The addon showed how there was complete reduction of blow outs in the highlights and such a better look with global illumination I was very impressed.
Now, many months later, returning to Blender after 2.79 did not do it for me migrating from C4D and Redshift (which now, may be possible, and better), this issue has arisen again.  I have e-cycles but haven't seriously learned it yet...if it's there (added as a native function) that would be as important to me as finding the plugin again.

Does ANY ONE know about this plugin?  Does anyone know if eevee, cycles or e-cycles has 20 F-Stops?  I'd be most grateful.

Comment: Sounds like you're referring to the Filmic view transform. There's an old video and [blog post by BlenderGuru](https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/secret-ingredient-photorealism) that vaguely matches the f-stop part that you're remembering.

Comment: Wow, that WAS the exact article I was vaguely remembering (from 2017) and the github was last committed in 2019, I'm very happy right now, tyvm.

Comment: The filmic view transform is included in Blender. It's the default in Blender 2.8x.

Comment: Ha!  Even better.  I'll start learning the nodes.